# Trim water damage, should I remove or let it dry?

Tags: leak, water-damage, laundry

My washer leaked due to a hole in the boot. We caught it within about 40 minutes and I quickly cleaned up with towels. The problem: the trim is swollen, discolored, and peeling a bit at the linolium contact edge.

I say we need to pull the trim and put in a new one. Its less than 5 feet of builder grade trim. I am concerned with mildew, mold, and other unseen damage if left.

My spouse says that its "probably fine" and they don't think we need to check behind it or replace that piece. They think if we just let it dry out and everything will be fine.

Comment: Swollen trim usually means MDF.  MDF/particle board does not like getting wet, like gremlins.  Removal of the swollen sections is usually the only fix.

Comment: It definitely sounds as if the trim need to be removed.  If it is swollen it is damaged.

Comment: "the trim is [made out of cardboard]" - It will "be fine", it will just always be swollen until you fix it. And unless you put real wood this time, it can happen again. - Don't need to check behind it; it looks like a stud that has gotten wet and is now dry; happens all the time. It becomes a problem if you *keep* letting it get it wet and it *stays* wet. - Laundry rooms have tile floors and edging, and/or you put it in a pan that has a drain... or this happens.